# Laravel 6.0 error in writing session ias failed to open file stream in windows

Tags: session, windows-10, php-7.2, laravel-6

i am doing a project in Laravel 6.0.0. I'm facing the error given below.

> file_put_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\lsapp\storage\framework/sessions/): failed to open stream: No such file or directory.

Already deleted the config.php file from bootstrap/cache/config.php.But its not working. Is there any workaround?

Comment: did you run `php artisan config:cache`?

Comment: Yes.. It is working because there was folder called sessions in framework. So i had to manually create the folder. Now it's working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete the file in `app/bootstrap/cache/config.php` then run artisan command to clear the configs `php artisan config:cache`. it will clear the cached configurations. then try opening your application( try with incognito mode also). If it's still not working then check the laravel project is setup correctly. Run `composer install` once.